# Cannot run program "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-sdk-tools, createprocess

I was using Android Studio (4.2.2) for a while on  Windows 10  with no problem when suddenly I couldn't run my application on my phone because it wasn't getting detected.
I tried using an AVD but that too wasn't getting detected.
I get this error:

> "Cannot run program
> "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe":
> CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

I've updated all my SDKs and even uninstalled and installed Android Studio and all it's components but nothing works.

Any solutions please!

Comment: Did my answer work?

Comment: @DEX7RA no because there was nothing wrong with the JDK location. But thanks anyway. I'm still new to Android Studio so some of your suggestions helped me with getting more familiar with the IDE

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
I think my adb.exe file corrupted so I downloaded another Platform-Tools file and deleted the previous one. This fixed the problem.

Comment: Make sure you don't just download "another" Platform-tools somewhere from the internet. Use the original version provided by Google e.g. for Windows https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r31.0.2-windows.zip